# How do I get rid of this bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNeqc.png)

I can't seem to find any solutions online so I figured I will post here.

Comment: run code without debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code settings (File -> Prefernces -> Settings -> Search for: `debug.toolBarLocation`):

[image]